logstash is not able to connect to elasticsearch
I am getting below error in logstash logs. I have configured the certs as configmap, after deploying it I am able to view the certs inside the pod as well but still getting the error.
        output {
          elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "https://es-es.eck-elasticsearch-es-http.eck.svc:9200" ]
            user => "elastic"
            password => "******"
            ssl_certificate_authorities => "/usr/share/logstash/certs/elastic-stack-ca.pem"
          }
        }
  podTemplate:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: eck-logstash
          image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.14.1
          volumeMounts:
            - name: logstash-ca
              mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/certs/
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: logstash-ca
          configMap:
            name: logstash-certs

ERROR FROM LOGSTASH LOGS
[ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Invalid setting for elasticsearch output plugin:

output {
elasticsearch {
# This setting must be a path
# ["File does not exist or cannot be opened /etc/logstash/certs/elastic-stack-ca.pem"]
ssl_certificate_authorities => "/etc/logstash/certs/elastic-stack-ca.pem"
...
}
}

I have extracted the certs from elastic search secret  as a '.pem' file.
Created the configmap
kubectl create configmap logstash-certs --from-file=./elastic-stack-ca.pem -n eck
Then mounted the configmap in the logstash pod as a volume.
